# Add papameters to AJAX response and then apply actions based on return parameter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a page (`page1`)that calls another page (`page2`) via AJAX.
How do I include parameters to page2 response and parse them in `success : function(data)`?
is there any way to add parameters to http response object and then access those parameters?

Reason:

page2 generates some HTML. It could be `good` or `bad` html message. If it is a good message, I need to add parameters (hidden) and then add that good message to `Success div`. if message is an error, I need to add this message to 'Error div'.

I can do it `bad way`: In Page2 I can add `hidden` element; then in page1 I can create some temp hidden div and add response to that div. Then access hidden element in hidden div and get it's value. Then get message from that div and paste it to designated div. But this seems to be too unprofessional.

**PAGE1:**

```
                function registeruser(){

                    jQuery(function($) {    
                        $.ajax( {           
                            url : "page2.php",
                            type : "POST",
                            data: {
                                registerFname : document.getElementById('registerFname').value, 
                                registerLname : document.getElementById('registerLname').value,
                                registerLEmail : document.getElementById('registerEmail').value,
                                registerPassword : document.getElementById('registerPassword').value,
                                ts : (new Date().getTime())
                            },

                            success : function(data) {
                            //need to apply logic here based on the return parameters
                            //if (SOME_PARAMETER === 'success'){
                            // document.getElementById('registerPresentation').innerHTML = data;  
                            //}
                            //else {
                            // document.getElementById('registerPresentationErrorDIV').innerHTML = data;  
                            //}

                            //need to get rid of item below
                                document.getElementById('registerPresentation').innerHTML = data;   

                            }
                        });
                    }); 

                }
```

Comment: alert data to check what is pouring in and apply the logic then

Comment: that is my question-- how do I do it?

Comment: just write alert(data);

Comment: alert(data) will bring me a page that is returned back... It is HTML

Comment: and if I understand correctly, you need to add params in that html itself , right?

Comment: page2 generates some HTML. It could be good or bad html message. If it is a good message, I need to add parameters (hidden) and then add that good message to Success div. if message is an error, I need to add this message to 'Error div'

Comment: use json , see my update ,hope this help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

page2.php

```
$a=array('err'=>0,html=>'dfhsxdfhbcfvyhdgfr');
```

json_encode($a);

page1.php

```
 success : function(data) {
  if (data.err=='0'){...}else{...}   

                        }
```

Comment: I have no issues parsing and rendering page 2. The only problem is to include `hidden` parameter to httpresponse object. Then, in page1 I need to do if (response==='good){ document.getElementById('registerPresentation').innerHTML = data; } else {document.getElementById('registerPresentationErrorDIV').innerHTML = data;}